# Mission control el capitan desktop thumbnail

Tags: snow-leopard, macos, spaces, mission-control, expose

I have recently moved from Snow Leopard to El Capitan, and there is something I'm missing currently and hope it is a gesture I don't know.

In Snow Leopard, when looking at all your desktop (Exposés and Spaces) it was possible to get what is actually Mission control, but on all the thumbnails of the other desktops.

In a quick view, it was then possible to expand all the windows of all the desktops. I don't know how to get that with El Capitan.

Thanks

[image: Mission control]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functionality of Spaces and Exposé have been combined into Mission Control (*Default shortcut is three finger swipe down, and icon [image: app icon for mission control]*). Mission Control changed the idea of spaces from a set number of desktops, to a horizontal line of desktops that can be created and deleted, and full screen apps. As of OSX 10.11, Mission control shows you the expose view of the current desktop, and if you hover over the "compressed" desktop bar [image: compressed osx el capitan mission control desktop view]it will expand to show you the desktops with proper window placement. [image: expanded osx el capitan mission control desktop view]. 
Using the 3 finger swipe from side to side while in Mission Control view will show the expose view of the desktop/app you are viewing. 
[image: expose view of current desktop in osx el capitan] [image: expose view of a different desktop in osx el capitan]. Unfortunately for you if you rely on one action that shows all expose views across all desktops, that is no longer available in El Capitan, however with the addition of full screen apps, the usability is higher than spaces.

Comment: I was aware of the gesture you mentioned, but if you insure El Capitan won't let me get the same feature as I was looking for, this is an answer too !

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for mission control by gestures ?

Settings -> Trackpad ->

[image]

Comment: not exactly, because this expands only the windows of the current active desktop, and even if I drag the pointer above the desktop bar atop the screen, the thumbnails of the others Desktop are not expanded. that is what I am looking for

Comment: like in this picture : http://talkbinary.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/Expose-Spaces.png