# Application name not appearing below thumbnail in mission control unless cursor is on it

Tags: macos, mojave, spaces, mission-control, expose

In mission control, I couldn't see Application names below thumbnails if the cursor is somewhere else. See this image.
[image]
If I move the cursor onto any thumbnail, then I'm seeing the application name.
[image]
Is there any setting that enables even if the cursor isn't hovering on the app thumbnail. Like images in this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/210711/208590). Desktop 1, Mail, Desktop 2, Desktop 3 are appearing all at once and cursor isn't on those thumbnails.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out once we have over 12 or so spaces it starts to have this zoom-on-hover effect with the space descriptions hidden. We cannot change this behavior. [Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/mac/comments/d02bdl/application_name_not_displaying_below_thumbnail/ez74gvw?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x).

Comment: Thank you! searched for this for an hour.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to turn on "group windows by application" in System Preferences -> Mission Control. This has a payoff which you have to decide :). You won't be able to see full window when they'll be stacked. This can be overcome by hovering the cursor on a window and press the space bar to zoom in only on that window. You can also swipe up with two fingers on a window group.

*Personally*, I keep grouping off and just quickly switch once or twice between mission control(swipe up) and app expose(swipe down) and see what windows are present. I just developed a habit, can be odd for people.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you said you go to mission control, click on a window group (because windows are grouped by application) and then opens app exposé to find the window you want. This is unnecessary because there are gestures to see individual windows on mission control: swipe up with two fingers on a group to zoom in on all windows of that group. Also, hover any window and press the space bar to zoom in on that window.

Comment: @Velociround no, I meant that I keep grouping off and do the said. it was a bit hidden in the word *just*. The two finger swipe up works just once. I wouldn't want to add such *inefficient* method to the answer.

Comment: How do you even know which app the window belongs when going to mission control, to only later use the app exposé? Wouldn't it be easier to just CMD + tab or open Spotlight and type it in?

Comment: mostly, I work in fairly distinguishable apps. Also, CMD tab or spotlight can give me the window I dont want to go into. Say I have A, B1, B2 open. CMD tab can give me B2 while I need B1. ( I think it is dependent on some recent activity. ) Everyone uses their Mac in a different way. I just compare the windows in both the views(mission control and app expose) and do the necessary. No big deal, I'll slightly edit your addition and close the discussion here.

Comment: @ankiiiiiii You guys completely changed the context. I'm asking about the thumbnails at the top, not the windows on the desktop. It turns out once we have over 12 or so spaces it starts to have this zoom-on-hover effect with the space descriptions hidden. We cannot change this behavior. See [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/mac/comments/d02bdl/application_name_not_displaying_below_thumbnail/ez74gvw?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x).

Comment: @duplex143 you didnt mention which thumbnails. Also, I think those names appear below desktop only when there's a full screen app.