# How to show file/window names in Mission Control?

Tags: macos, mission-control

I need to switch between windows often across apps. I have 4 terminals open, 5 projects in Visual Studio Code, 4 github repos open in Sublime Merge, 3 Finder windows, 6 Chrome windows, and on top of that 1 each of Music, Preview, Octave, SlickEdit, TextEdit

I need to switch between VSCode, Sublime Merge, and Terminal most often and to specific windows but as you can see from the screenshot below it's difficult to figre out which window is which

[image: mission control]

I can hover over each window one at time and it will show a title but it's really tedious to hover over several windows.

Is there a way to get Mission Control to always draw the titles over every window?

Comment: I suggest using app exposè, which is the opposite gesture of mission control, generally. Also you can turn on group windows by application in sys pref  > mission control.

Comment: How does app exposé help here? I’m switching from say vscode to the terminal or from the terminal to sublime merge. are you suggesting first mission control to select the app followed by app exposé ? That sounds almost as tedious as hovering over all the windows .  Or is there some other flow you’re suggesting?

Comment: no I am suggesting what you just said.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it. Maybe I'll get used to it.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem and found a method that could be helpful:
Check the "Group windows by application" option in Mission control in the system preference. It will group windows of the same application but show the name of the application even if there is only one window. It might be a problem if you need to switch windows within the same application but helps for switching between applications, which is what I need.

Comment: Yeah this can do it in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

I keep one app on one desktop, so I switch to the relevant desktop, and use App Exposè which is generally three finger swipe down. It shows the window name below each window and hovering isn't required.

- [Application name not appearing below thumbnail in mission control unless cursor is on it](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/368295/application-name-not-appearing-below-thumbnail-in-mission-control-unless-cursor)
- [What is an efficient way for developers / power users to use OSX window management and Spaces on a single screen?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/179376/what-is-an-efficient-way-for-developers-power-users-to-use-osx-window-manageme?rq=1)

Comment: Multiple desktops are not useful for me. More often than not I need to reference 2 or more things at once. An answer in stackoverflow in Chome will looking at my editor, an image in Photoshop while referencing a youtube video. Watching for error messages in the terminal while editing text in my editor. In the screen above I have a Coursera course where I need to see 1 Octave window, 1 or 2 preview windows and 1 or 2 chrome windows at the same time.